# Ubuntu 14.04 with unrecognized monitor (or without monitor) - boot problem

Tags: 14.04, xorg, monitor

I've `Ubuntu 14.04` installed on my computer. I need to start it even if not any monitor is plugged.

Basically I need to do that because at the startup **my monitor isn't recognized** but plugged in. That's why I need to continue the startup even if `X` doesn't see a plugged monitor.

If there isn't any monitor, my computer doesn't start at all.

I thought the problem came from the `Xserver` but it's long before that (see Edit3) but I did some work on `X server` anyway to be sure the problem didn't come form here.

I tried to add manually a Xorg configuration file. Here is my file

```
#/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier             "Monitor0"
    Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier             "graphic_card0"
    Driver                 "intel"
    BusID                  "PCI:0:2:0"
    #Driver                 "vesa" #Choose the driver used for this monitor
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier             "Screen0"  #Collapse Monitor and Device section to Screen section
    Device                 "graphic_card0"
    Monitor                "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth           24 #Choose the depth (16||24)
    SubSection             "Display"
        Depth              24
        Modes              "1920x1080_60.00" #Choose the resolution
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I have found inspiration on [ArchLinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg#Monitor_settings) and [Unix StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182279/unable-to-start-x-server-with-no-screens-no-xorg-config-to-edit)

but it's still not working.

Note :

1. `PCI:0:2:0` comes from the result of the command :

   `lspci | grep VGA`

   `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView Gen7 (rev 0e)`

I also tried this via SSH

1. To stop `lightdm`
2. To create `xorg.conf.new` file with `Xorg -configure` as root.
3. rename `xorg.conf.new` as `xorg.conf`

Here is the generated file :

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "NoAccel"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "AccelMethod"           # <str>
        #Option     "Backlight"             # <str>
        #Option     "DRI"                   # <str>
        #Option     "Present"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ColorKey"              # <i>
        #Option     "VideoKey"              # <i>
        #Option     "Tiling"                # [<bool>]
        #Option     "LinearFramebuffer"     # [<bool>]
        #Option     "VSync"                 # [<bool>]
        #Option     "PageFlip"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SwapbuffersWait"       # [<bool>]
        #Option     "TripleBuffer"          # [<bool>]
        #Option     "XvPreferOverlay"       # [<bool>]
        #Option     "HotPlug"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ReprobeOutputs"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DeleteUnusedDP12Displays"  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "XvMC"                  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"           # <str>
        #Option     "VirtualHeads"          # <i>
        #Option     "TearFree"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "PerCrtcPixmaps"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "FallbackDebug"         # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DebugFlushBatches"     # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DebugFlushCaches"      # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DebugWait"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "BufferCache"           # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

It's still not working.

It seems that not any files is read or is taking in account.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thank you in advance.

**Edit:**
Here is the content of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` (too big to be written here) : [Xorg.log](http://pastie.org/private/59a0lnyz9gi8rroytua)

**Edit2:**
If I add `i915.modeset=1` on the grub, it's better because I can see the grub if I plug a monitor after the startup. But the grub seems to be shown only when I plug it, not before..

**Edit3: **
The problem seems to come from a thing between the hardware and the boot. When I've added `i915.modeset=1` my computer doesn't start without a plugged monitor but wait until one is plugged. After that, it starts normally. Before nothing happened at all. That means `i915.modeset=1` has an impact on my bootload. I don't know how or where but it seems to.

Comment: See what happens if you just plug a cable into the video port.

Comment: I tried without screen at the other end of the cable. It's still not working. But when I really plug a screen it's working.

Comment: Yeah. Try that.

Comment: I did it. Without a cable or with a cable without screen at the other end it's not working.

Comment: Does the computer boot with a monitor plugged in?

Comment: Yes. Perfectly. It seems (I'm not completely sure) that the X server failed (or wait) that a monitor is plugged.

Comment: Can you upload the log?

Comment: Which log do you want? dmesg? xorg? Are those logs still interesting after an hard reboot? Because when I don't have any screen (after starting without monitor and then plugged it) I have to manually reboot it.

Comment: The xorg log. It might have some error that's easy to diagnose.

Comment: I've added it at the end of my post but it seems that the first start (without monitor) isn't recorded.

Comment: That would mean the X server isn't starting, then.

Comment: I think it's waiting to have a plugged monitor to start.

Comment: Your question states that you can SSH into it. Do you want to setup a VNC connection to it or something?

Comment: I want to start Ubuntu Desktop even if there isn't any monitor because it will have one in the futur.

Comment: If you're not using the computer and it works fine with a monitor, I don't see the problem.

Comment: I want to start it even if there isn't any monitor plugged in. That means I need to test the startup without any monitor. And this step doesn't work.

Comment: I've added a little evolution (Edit2)

Comment: Why do you want to start it, though? You know it works fine, and you don't need to use it.

Comment: I've added some details on my post (on top). I need to start it anyway because on the startup my screen isn't recognized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally fixed this problem. The problem came from the `grub`.This is my found way.

```
#/etc/X11/xorg.conf

Section "Device"
  Identifier "card0"
  Driver "intel"
  VendorName  "INTEL Corporation"
  #Option "NoDDC"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
  Identifier "fake_monitor"
  VendorName "Unknown"
  HorizSync 30-83
  VertRefresh 56-75
  Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
  Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1080_60.00" 
EndSection

Section "Screen"
  Identifier "screen_without_monitor"
  Device "card0"
  Monitor "fake_monitor"
  SubSection "Display"
    Modes "1920x1080_60.00"
  EndSubSection
EndSection
```

And the most important file:

```
# /etc/default/grub

GRUB_DEFAULT=10
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.modeset=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=«
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920X1080
```

After editing `/etc/default/grub` do not forget to run `sudo update-grub`. This will generate the true `grub.cfg` file read during the boot.

This forces my computer to start even if there's not any monitor plugged.

Note: If not any monitor is plugged at all, the screen will be black until I connect on the computer (with `TeamViewer` for example) but the computer will start anyway.

I hope this will help someone else.

Comment: what exactly has you chenged in the files??

Comment: I've created `xorg.conf` and updated `/etc/default/grub`. Mostly for the variable `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` if I remember well.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this. Either get a dummy plug for the VGA port to simulate a monitor. (you can make them also)

A VGA dummy plug is a simple hack to fool the GPU and Windows by let them thinking there is a monitor plugged on a card. 
The VGA dummy principle is simple: simulating the monitor RGB channels load with 3 resistors. Any resistor between 50 and 150 ohms is okay.

You will need the DVI-VGA adapter that ships with every GFX card, the resistors and a clipper. You could use scissors or a nail clipper, the wire is soft.

Bend one leg of the resistor around till it is parallel to the other then clip off the long leg so it is the same length as the bent leg.

The wire is just the right gauge to slide into the VGA plus securely.

Push it home. Note you want to bridge the top three pins on the right with the pins directly below one-to-one.. Hold the plug so the wide part is up top.

Alternate the resistors so the leg of one is against the body of another to avoid shorting out the jumpers.

Guide with pictures : http://www.overclock.net/t/384733/the-30-second-dummy-plug

Guide 2 : http://www.geeks3d.com/20091230/vga-hack-how-to-make-a-vga-dummy-plug/

OR use a dummy driver like So

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-dummy
```

Then configure the xorg.conf file:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
    Driver      "dummy"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
    HorizSync 31.5-48.5
    VertRefresh 50-70
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Monitor     "Configured Monitor"
    Device      "Configured Video Device"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1024x800"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Then restart. And hopefully works.

Comment: I tried that too but I can't install `xserver-xorg-video-dummy` because I have troubles with `xorg-video-abi-15` and `xserver-xorg-core`. Visibly it's not possible to install it without corrupting the current state. I tried to stop `lightdm` service but it's still not working.

Comment: I've added an `xorg.conf` file on `/etc/X11/` and it's well written because it's working when I'm doing `sudo restart lightdm`. I think my problem now is to force `X` to start by reading this file instead of waiting a plugged monitor.

Comment: It seems to me like a dummy plug would be the way to go here. Especially if you want to do this without corrupting the original driver.

I have edited my original answer to provide instructions how to make one but they can easily be bought.

Comment: Thank for your time. i've also edited my post to explain why I needed to do that. In fact I've a monitor plugged in but it's not recognized. That means I can't apply your second method.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm unable to provide any further help :(